# Where are the map files stored when rosrun map_server map_saver is run

Tags: ros, map-saver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used this command to store map

`rosrun map_server map_saver static_map:=dynamic_map`

This is the output i got:

Waiting for the map
Received a 1984 X 1984 map @ 0.050 m/pix
Writing map occupancy data to map.pgm
Writing map occupancy data to map.yaml
Done

Where are these maps physically stored? If i want to use them again how do i load them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368509/where-are-the-map-files-stored-when-rosrun-map_server-map_saver-is-run/) by [Krush](https://answers.ros.org/users/66617/krush/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

By default the maps are stored on the same location where you run the command with the names to `map.pgm` and `map.yaml`.

If you want to specify a different path and filename you can use the `-f` option.  There are quite more parameters, and instructions on how to use `map_server` on its wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2020-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bekirbostanci](https://answers.ros.org/users/45026/bekirbostanci/) on 2020-12-29**:
map yaml and pgm files do not have to be in the same path. If you edit yaml file you can see pgm file path in there.